# Ruby on Rails Active Admin: Email Not Displaying after Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth, activeadmin

So I have a regular user, an admin user, and an oauth user type.  I changed quite a few things to get them to work right, but now active admin is no longer displaying the email address in the upper-right hand corner when logging in.

My apps/admin/user.rb (formerly admin_user.rb) is just the regular ActiveAdmin user... so no point in posting that.

Here's the file that has changed (users.rb in the models.)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
acts_as_voter

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, 
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :provider, :uid, :name,     :remember_me
# attr_accessible :title, :body
has_many :posts
has_many :tasks
has_many :dailies
has_many :authentications



 def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
   create! do |user|
   user.provider = auth['provider']
   user.uid = auth['uid']
   user.password = user.password_confirmation = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(n=6)
   if auth['info']
     user.name = auth['info']['name'] || ""
     user.email = auth['info']['email'] || ""
   end
   end
  end
 end
```

Am I missing an index or something?

I tried adding:

```
index({ email: 1 }, { unique: true, background: true })
```

But it told me the index method was not defined...

(While I'm at it I should also ask: How does that function work? How do I get the current users email/username to display somewhere after a successful login? And how do I get a "login" link to switch to a "logout" link once you're logged in?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. This should be simple enough.

Anyone with a three-stage user solution (users, admin users, oauth users) might run into this problem. (I only discovered the solution after finally getting Oauth to work.) After getting something like OmniAuth working the tendency is for Active-Admin to default to the Name (i.e. Facebook username) instead of the email address. This is why it shows nothing for your normal users because, by default, they don't have usernames. Just email addresses.

All you have to do is find the part of the code where it's setting the display to name and switch it back to email. (wherever that may be in your case.)